# Postfix accepts unauthorized requests

Tags: postfix, sasl, smtpd

Here is an excerpt of my Postfix configuration:

```
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
```

I now want to test that Postfix really only accepts messages from authenticated users.
Therefor I used telnet (directly on the server) and send a mail - which was successful even though I did not perform any authentication in the telnet session.
Is that the expected behaviour? The last line of the excerpt suggests that the test should not have worked!?

Thanks!

Comment: Postfix accepts mail to local addresses and virtual aliases by default.  Did you test it for a foreign domain?

Comment: Please provide us the full output from your telnet session (when testing authentication) like this [question](http://serverfault.com/q/587107/218590)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
```

Not tested, but should work AFAIK. You should get the `REJECT` error after sending the receiving address.