# block your own domain in postfix sending mails via telnet HELO

Tags: postfix

On my postfix/courier debian 9 server I can send mails via telnet with the result

```
 250 2.1.0 Ok
```

Now I try to block users from sending mails via telnet HELO comand using my own domain without authentification.

I added this in my postfix `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_helo_access,
    ...
```

This is my file `/etc/postfix/check_helo_access`:

```
/mydomain\.de$/                 550 Forged HELO/EHLO command
```

Now this kind of works, but when I try to send email via telnet it is blocked, but I get the error:

```
451 4.3.5 <mydomain.de>: Helo command rejected: Server configuration error
```

I also tried settin just this in `/etc/postfix/check_helo_access`:

```
mydomain.de REJECT
```

resulting in the same errormessage. The same error, if I set the option in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` instead of `smtpd_helo_restrictions`.

How do I configure this right, so I get a sound error message in telnet? Or is this the correct way and the error message is just misleading?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different [Postfix lookup table types](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types):

> - `hash`
>
>   An indexed file type based on hashing. This is available only on
>     systems with support for Berkeley DB databases. Public database files
>     are created with the [postmap(1)](http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html) or [postalias(1)](http://www.postfix.org/postalias.1.html) command, and
>     private databases are maintained by Postfix daemons. The database name
>     as used in `hash:table` is the database file name without the `.db`
>     suffix.
> - `pcre` (read-only)
>
>   A lookup table based on Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. The
>     file format is described in [pcre_table(5)](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html). The lookup table name
>     as used in `pcre:table` is the name of the regular expression file.

- If you wish to use

  ```
  /example\.com$/   550   Forged HELO/EHLO command
  ```

  you need

  ```
  check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/check_helo_access
  ```

  and have the Postfix built with [PCRE support](http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html). In Debian 9, you'd need the [`postfix-pcre`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/postfix-pcre).
- With

  ```
  check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_helo_access
  ```

  you must use the format

  ```
  example.com   550   Forged HELO/EHLO command
  ```

  and remember to perform `postmap /etc/postfix/check_helo_access` after modifications.

As an additional hint, you could fire all `HELO`, sender and recipient restrictions after the full `HELO`, `MAIL FROM` & `RCPT TO` sequence by putting them all into [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions). This way you won't lose information on who was trying to send mail to whom, as you would if you reject the mail right after the `HELO`. This just makes the debugging and the forensics a lot easier.

Comment: Great! What would be the line to add for firing them all?